# EF.core One to many referencing the same table

Tags: entity-framework

EF.core beginner here.
In my app I have Persons. These are connected to other persons (in that same table), and those connections have a 'level'. I've added a join table called connection to store who is connected to who and on what level. When trying to do an Add-migration i get the following error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Connection.Person' of type 'Person'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the model.

There is no problem on my other join tables that reference two different tables. What am i missing here?

I'm using EF.core 1.1, with .net 4.5, code below

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }                        
    public List<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
}

public class Connection
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; } 
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public int SecondPersonId { get; set; }
    public Person SecondPerson { get; set; }
    public int ConnectionLevelId { get; set; } // connection Level
    public ConnectionLevel Level { get; set; }
}

public class ConnectionLevel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //rights
}

public class testContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ConnectionLevel> ConnectionLevels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Connection>().HasKey(s => new { s.PersonId, s.SecondPersonId });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Person.Connections the list of Connections who refer to the current Person by PersonId, or by SecondPersonId?  That's what the error is asking.

Comment: How do i tell EF that Person.Connections refers to PersonId is my next question then :)

Comment: Use `InverseProperty` attribute or fluent API. See [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Comment: I'm not completely sure what to do with InverseProperty when looking at the documentation in this case. Everything i can find is talking about different properties or List<>

Comment: Indeed, you have a `List<Connection> Connections` property in `Person`, decorate it with `[InverseProperty("Person")]`, thus telling EF that `Person.Connections` and `Connection.Person` form the relationship.